# Excel formula to get number of days between two dates in months with precision

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

what's the formula to get number of days between two dates in months with days precision.

For example: the number of days between 01-01-2017 & 14-02-2017 these two dates is 45 days. (31 days + 14 days - including both) So I'm expecting 1 month 14 days as output. So the format should be 1.14 (1 month 14 days)

Edit:
There is no assumption of 30 days in a month. I'm expecting exact calendar difference.

Comment: are to we assume a 30 day month?  for example if it is `10.2 - 2.20`

Comment: @ScottCraner There is no assumption of 30 days in a month. I'm expecting exact calendar difference.

Comment: So `2.4` is Feb 4th?

Comment: So you have two date and you want the ouput to be `M.D`

Comment: @Sainath You need to be more specific to list exactly how you want to output this. Do you want it outputted as a *string* or as a *number*? If you want the output to be a number, you would have to distinguish the difference between, for example `2.1` and `2.10`.

Comment: @ScottCraner sorry I didn't mean that actually, I provided example now. hope that makes it clear.

Comment: You are assuming that January has 30 days it has 31 and as such the answer would be 1.13 not 1.14

Comment: @Sainath Your edits still don't tell me if you want the output to be a string or a number. Also, the difference between Jan. 1 and Feb 14 is one month and *13* days, not 14.

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889, exactly, I'm looking for number format only. what I all wanted is, difference between two dates is less than or equals 6 months or greater than 6 months. How do I do that?

Comment: @Sainath My point is that if you output a number, there is no way to distinguish between for example, `2.1` and `2.10` since they are mathematically equivalent.

Comment: That is a totally different question than the one you have posted.

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 okay, in that case, if the output is in string format, then how can I apply a filter on the column to filer out the criteria as I mentioned above?

Comment: @Sainath Wait, you now only want to know if the difference is greater than or less than 6 months? Before I or ScottCraner attempts to answer this question again, **please edit your original post to explain in detail exactly what you want to accomplish**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With data in **A1** and **B1**, in **C1** enter:

```
=DATEDIF(A1,B1,"m") & "." & DATEDIF(A1,B1,"md")
```

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

The formula gives a text value.  To convert to number and preserve formatting, select the cells in column **C** containing the formula and run this short macro:

```
Sub KonverToNumber()
    Dim r As Range, L As Long, T As String
    Dim rr As Range

    For Each r In Selection
        Set rr = r.Offset(0, 1)
        T = r.Text
        v = CDbl(T)
        L = Len(Split(T, ".")(1))
        If L = 2 Then
           rr.NumberFormat = "0.00"
        Else
            rr.NumberFormat = "0.0"
        End If
        rr.Value = v
    Next r
End Sub
```

*The results will be in column **D***

[image]

Comment: apparently we are answering the wrong question.  See the last few comments above.

Comment: Confused with my comment or with OP?

Comment: @Gary's Student - yes this is what exactly I'm looking for. If I add one to the second parameter then I'm getting the number of days between two dates. =DATEDIF(A1,B1,"m") & "." & DATEDIF(A1,B1,"md")+1

Comment: @Sainath  The need to add ***1*** to the calculation comes from the decision to include or exclude the endpoints................... **REMEMBER** my answer is just a *String* that looks like a *Number*

Comment: @Gary'sStudent yes, =VALUE(DATEDIF(A1,B1,"m") & "." & DATEDIF(A1,B1,"md")+1) this will do the work. thanks!

Comment: @ScottCraner  The question seems to evolve over time...............its like answering a question about a protozoa that after a few billion years becomes ... Garys Student.

Comment: @Sainath  It is better to leave the value as *Text*.  That way you can tell the difference between ***9.1*** and ***9.10***

Answer (score 2):

If you want "Years, Months, Days" to show up in one cell this is the formula.

```
= DATEDIF(D17,E17,"y") & " Years, " & 
  DATEDIF(D17,E17,"ym") & " Months, " &
  DATEDIF(D17,E17,"md") & " Days"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=DATEDIF(A1,B1,"m") & "." & B1-DATE(YEAR(B1),MONTH(B1)-IF(DAY(A1)>DAY(B1),1,0),DAY(A1))+1
```

[image]

Comment: DATEDIF function can be used for that simply, but what I'm looking for is exact precision in days when we use the function DATEDIF(date1, date2, "m"), this will round up only months not in days.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, I've been using this method to do exactly that.
Assume the following:
D17 is the Start Date
E17 is the End Date

If you used the following formula:
=DATEDIF(D17,E17,"y") & "years, " & DATEDIF(D17,E17),"ym") & "months, " & E17-DATE(YEAR(E17),MONTH(E17),1) & "days"

To get the exact format you want, you might want to edit the formula to look something like this:
=DATEDIF(D17,E17),"ym") & "." & E17-DATE(YEAR(E17),MONTH(E17),1)

Hope this works as well for you as it does me.